# c# OledbException was handled error

Tags: c#, exception, oledb

I tried tons of possible ways but to no avail, and now i have **"OledbException was unhandled"** while trying to **catch and throw exception**. Please advise thanks!

(Assume new data inputs are all strings not integer.)

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //connect to database
        string strOleDbConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Project.mdb";
        OleDbConnection objConnection = new OleDbConnection(strOleDbConnectionString);

        objConnection.Open();
        string newTagID = textBox1.Text;
        string newUser = textBox2.Text;
        string newAge = textBox3.Text;
        string newPhoneNumber = textBox4.Text;

        string InsertNewRecord = "INSERT INTO jiahe ([Tag ID], [User], [Age], [Phone Number]) VALUES ('" + newTagID + "', '" + newUser + "', '" + newAge + "', '" + newPhoneNumber + "')";
        OleDbCommand InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(InsertNewRecord, objConnection);

        try
        {
            InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@[Tag ID]", newTagID);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@[User]", newUser);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@[Age]", newAge);
            InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@[Phone Number]", newPhoneNumber);
            InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Record Added!");
        }

        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        finally
        {
            objConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

Comment: How come when i try to input integers everything worked fine? I thought it should be a string when i wrap User, Age, etc with ' '?

Comment: If you're going to use parameters for your command (good) then you don't concatenate the data into the SQL. Also,  you're throwing an exception from the exception handler... is any/all of this intentional?

Comment: I guessed i wrote the exception handler blindly, thanks for highlighting!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is: why are you getting "OledbException was unhandled".

So the answer to your question (but not to your problem) is that you are re-throwing an exception with throw. Instead of that, do something like:

```
 MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
```

That will show you what is the real error behind your code, and you will have handled the exception.

The oleDBException is probably coming because you should use the following to define the SQL command:

```
 string InsertNewRecord = "INSERT INTO jiahe ([Tag ID], [User], [Age], [Phone Number]) VALUES (?newTagID, ?newUser, ?newAge,?newPhoneNumber)";
```

And then the rest of code will set those parameters replacing the @xxx in the command with actual values. The AddParameter will add quotes, so you do not have to.

Comment: OleDb uses positional, rather than named parameters. The "@__" names should be "?" instead.  Also, a key feature of parameters is that it's wrong to characterize them by saying other code will replace the "@xxx" in the command. This _NEVER_ happens. Rather, separate blocks are transmitted to the server for the code and the data. This is what makes parameters secure.

Comment: Joel did you mean replace @___ with ? or ?xxx?